# Xcode: Not on any development teams

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm developing and selling apps on the Mac App Store and today, when I wanted to refresh and add new provisioning profile in Xcode (Organiser), this error showed up:

[image: Not on any development teams]

*(Not on any development teams. The indicated user is not on any development teams)*

When I try to create a new provisioning profile in Xcode, a modal form shows up and there is a drop down list named "Team", which is completely empty. The App ID, devices list etc. are empty too…

[image: Create a new provisioning profile]

Does anyone know what Apple changed? It worked for years. I clicked through iTunes Connect and the Development centre and I did not find any settings for teams whatsoever. I guess that's something new, since I did not even got a google hit on the error message.

Comment: Please try to refresh the Organizer in XCode. Hope it helps

Answer (score 96):

In Xcode > Preferences > Accounts, try deleting `-` the selected (problem) account and then adding `+` again. This quickly fixed the issue for me.

Background: I'm in both Mac & iOS Developer Programs. Unannounced, the Mac Developer side was no longer provisioned. Looking at Accounts, showed only iOS program signing identities and provisioning profiles. The above steps restored Xcode and my Mac apps.

Comment: Updated to Xcode 6.1 and all of a sudden I am no longer on any development teams.  I (independently) did the above, remove and add my AppleID back, and my teams came back.   Good advice!

Comment: Clicking "-" didn't remove the selected account until I rebooted my Mac. Something must've been really hosed.

Answer (score 34):

If anyone comes here after finding the issue in XCode 6.1, simply remove then re-add your Apple ID. Nothing worked for me until I did that.

Comment: Xcode 6.1, OSX 10.9.4, removing and adding the account still gives me a message that says "Not on Any Development Teams". I was able to export the IPA and then use `Application Loader` to upload to iTunesConnect, using the same account I was trying to use in Xcode.

Comment: My Xcode 6.1 was crashing whenever it had to fetch teams (anywhere). I finally fixed it by removing all of my old/expired Apple developer accounts from Xcode preferences.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution which worked for me. Simples!

Comment: Had the same issue on the Xcode 7 beta, this fixed it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

I did what Iniles did, but I can't comment on his answer. Here are the steps, since they didn't outline them:

- Go to iOS Dev Center
- Select 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' in the top right.  (This won't be there if your membership has expired.)
- Select 'Certificates'
- Click on your username
- Select 'Download'
- Do the same for your Distribution Certificate. Mine didn't work till I downloaded both.
- Open the file, should auto open in Keychain Access. If it doesn't, open Keychain Access and drag over the file into your 'login' keychain.

Make sure the certificate is being installed in your 'login' keychain in Keychain Access. I once had an issue where it was going to the wrong place.

I'd also like to note that I had to do this every time I updated the provisioning profiles, so I think it might be a bug with their server right now.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix the issue simply by launching `Keychain`, then clicking *Refresh* in *Xcode Organizer*.

Nothing special to do in Keychain, just launch the app and have it running while clicking Refresh.

Comment: With or without Keychain running?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today. I was able to get around it by (re)downloading my developer and distribution certificates from the portal and re-adding them to my keychain. It worked in my n=1 case, hopefully it helps others too.

Comment: It did not help for me, however, after renewing my enrollment, it suddenly worked again :-\

Answer (score 2):

Some hours after renewing my developer enrollment, it worked again… However due getting really mad, I deleted, regenerated and imported/exported the certificates like a boss, so I'm not sure what the real solution was.

Comment: Try Refreshing XCode organizer. When it prompts for iTunes login, give your development credentials. And that's it

Comment: @septi i'm in the same horrible situation now.  nothing is helping and i did not upgrade Xcode or Mac OS or anything else.  i did not change anything recently either.  did you find any solution?  i'm on 4 teams and i get this message every time now :-(

Comment: It works for me again, just try one (all) of these instructions here and it will work again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Coming late to this question but for any developers having this issue in 2016+, I got it to work by removing my Apple ID under "Accounts" and then re-adding it. I had previously had " is not on any development teams" under Team Name. After re-adding, my Apple ID was automatically signed up for the free tier. The problem probably stems from having an old Mac with XCode installed before the free tier was introduced.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening may be because the developer account is not renewed.
May be using earlier Xcode versions can help to take ipa build until the developer account is renewed.

Note: Apple Development ECO system is getting corrupted. Few days back, they increased the iOS developers fees to 79 Pounds from 60 Pounds in UK. There was no proper information/announcement on this either on the payment page or the iOS developer page.